# SMB administrative Shares (C$) not accessible on a server running SharePoint - WebDAV MiniRedir reports PROPFIND not implemented

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, http, server-message-block, webdav

I've just moved in for a new job, so not much detail. My workstation runs Windows 7. We have a SharePoint 2007 server (Windows 2003) for development which fails to provide access via SMB administrative shares like \server\c$. I can use \mywin7\c$ backwards from a terminal session on that server.

Looking at the packets I see that the \server\share requests are handled by IIS 6 which renders http status 501 Not Implemented in response to PROPFIND verb WebDAV requests.

PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600
Depth: 0
translate: f
Content-Length: 0
Host: server

HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2009 08:03:25 GMT

How can I force the use of SMB over HTTP/WebDAV for such requests?

SMB Tree Connect AndX Request, Path: \host\c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It struck me that some of the services might be not running. I started the "**Server**" service using **services.msc** and UNC works again. So does the Visual Studio Remote Debugger. Hallelujah.